# Disable ec2 instance termination protection with Ansible

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I'm currently enabling `termination_protection` for all instances created with Ansible to prevent accidental termination from the console etc. Now I want to be able to terminate specific instances with Ansible but I can't figure out how to disable termination protection on them.

This is what I thought would do the trick:

```
- name: Disable termination protection
  ec2:
    instance_ids: "{{ instance_ids }}"
    region: "{{ aws_region }}"
    termination_protection: no
```

How ever I get this error message when running it:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
  "changed": false, 
  "failed": true, 
  "msg": "image parameter is required for new instance"
}
```

It looks like Ansible is interpreting my script as an instance creation request.

Is there a way to change `termination protection` with another module? The only other way I can think of is to use **aws cli** through a `shell` task in Ansible but that is a bit hacky.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's take a look into the [source code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/devel/cloud/amazon/ec2.py).

States `running` and `stopped` calls `startstop_instances()`.
State `restarted` calls `restart_instances()`.
Both this functions honor `source_dest_check` and `termination_protection` attributes values.

So you can call:

```
 - ec2:
     instance_ids: "{{ instance_ids }}"
     state: restarted
     region: "{{ aws_region }}"
     termination_protection: no
```

if you don't mind your servers to be restarted.

Or query current states with `ec2_remote_facts` and call `ec2` module with that states as parameter – this will change `termination_protection`, but will keep instances' states untouched.